# Python/Django: What does this line do?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

New to Django

This code adds a user submitted item to a table. Can I get a full explanation of what the return statement is doing? Is it basically returning a list item and saying replace `%s` with `item.text`?

```
def add(request):
  item = LineItem(text=request.POST["text"])
  item.save()
  return HttpResponse("<li>%s</li>" % item.text)
```

Answer (score 3):

The text `"<li>%s</li>" % item.text` is a python [string formatting expression](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting).

The `%s` part of the string is a placeholder string, and to fill it python will replace that placeholder with `str(item.text)`.

The result is returned as a HTTP response, presumably to be used by an AJAX call (it's not a full HTML page).

Answer (score 0):

> Is it basically returning a list item and saying replace %s with item.text

Yup.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah -- the "string %s" % string construct is just a way of writing a string with variables in it. The %s is a placeholder for the variable item.text that is being inserted into the string.

It's a string formatting operation. See details here:

http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting